# A good name for live system performance testing?

Tags: automated-testing, terminology, monitoring

We have a JMeter end-2-end test running on a live system. The test represents an important user scenario. This test results in time metrics for each step in that scenario. These metrics are input to a monitoring system to visualize these metrics over time. It's not a stress test; it's a single instance test that runs every 15 minutes. The test provides us first line info about the performance of the system. The monitoring notifies us when the step time deviates from its mean.

Is there a common name for this practice? Is this still "testing"? Or is this more in the "monitoring" domain?

Comment: Sounds like monitoring to me - generates input for monitor. Testing checks the returned values.

Answer (score 2):

This is monitoring which produces metrics over time.

**Monitoring**:

- Production Performance Monitoring
- Production Network Monitoring
- Production Security Monitoring
- Production Load Monitoring

**Metrics**:

- Production Performance Metrics
- Production Network Metrics
- Production Security Metrics
- Production Load Metrics

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely still testing, but when you are running tests on production systems, the terminology often changes.

These become

- Performance Metrics (seconds to perform particular tasks)
- Reconciliation Metrics (automated checks that the source data has been loaded successfully into the target data area)
- Other types of system monitoring like 'overall data load time', 'disk free space', '%memory usage', 'Peak IO', etc.

Answer (score 0):

*Here is an article about testing in production that covers this topic nicely.*
[Testing in Production: How we combined tests with monitoring](https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/amp.theguardian.com/info/developer-blog/2016/dec/20/testing-in-production-rethinking-the-conventional-deployment-pipeline)

*The term for this is "**synthetic monitoring**".*